# How can I resolve an issue with a Sigma wireless computer signal that cuts out?

Tags: computer

I have a basic Sigma wireless computer. It has served me well (one on each of my two bikes), but lately, it has been cutting out during a ride.

Usually, it starts working again on its own, but I have lost my ride data for the time it is off. I have changed batteries, checked distances, and cleaned all surfaces.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

With simple wireless bike computers the antenna for communication with the wheel sensor is actually in the computer’s mount. There are two small contacts. It’s conceivable that these contacts no longer work reliably or that the antenna itself is starting to break. Did you clean those pads and pins? You could try getting a replacement mount for cheap or free. At least the Sigma ones are mostly interchangeable. Most bike shops probably have dozens in their part bin.

I’d also make sure that the wheel magnet is really well aligned.